# Corresponding DropDownButtonFormFields in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I'm implementing corresponding dropdowns (where the options of the second dropdown depend on the first like so) that uses a list of objects in this format:

```
List<State> states = [
  new State(stateId: 1, stateName: "New York", cities: [
    new City(cityId: 1, cityName: "New York City"),
    new City(cityId: 2, cityName: "Buffalo") ...
```

And the widget code is like so:

```
children: <Widget>[
                DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'State'),
                  value: selectedStateId,
                  items: states.map((State state) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                      value: state.stateId,
                      child: new Text(states.singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == state.stateId).stateName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (int newStateId) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.selectedCityId = states.singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == newStateId).cities[0].cityId; // set to first city for this state
                      this.selectedStateId = = newStateId;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                  value: selectedCityId,
                  items: states.singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == selectedStateId)
                      .cities
                      .map((City city) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                      value: city.cityId,
                      child: new Text(states
                          .singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == selectedStateId).cities.singleWhere((x) => x.cityId == city.cityId).cityName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (int newCityId) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.selectedCityId = newCityId;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
```

When I change the State dropdown in this example, I get an error:
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value".

The "1" in the above error corresponds to whatever the selected city value was prior to changing the state, so I know that the error relates to the fact that it's still looking for the old selectedCityId and it is no longer in the item list, but I'm not sure why as I've changed that value in setState. A key to this issue, I believe, is the same exact code works if I just change the DropDownButtonFormField to regular DropDownButtons, but I'd like to use the built in label text that comes along with the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**
You can use `key: UniqueKey()` int City `DropdownButtonFormField`

```
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
```

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can set `selectedStateId` and `selectedCityId` to `states`'s attribute 
You can not directly set to a value like `selectedStateId = 1`, because system will compare address 
code snippet

```
  int selectedStateId;
  int selectedCityId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedStateId = states[0].stateId;
    selectedCityId = states[0].cities[0].cityId;
    super.initState();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class City {
  int cityId;
  String cityName;
  City({this.cityId, this.cityName});
}

class CountryState {
  int stateId;
  String stateName;
  List<City> cities;
  CountryState({this.stateId, this.stateName, this.cities});
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  List<CountryState> states = [
    CountryState(stateId: 1, stateName: " York", cities: [
      City(cityId: 1, cityName: "York City"),
      City(cityId: 2, cityName: "Buffalo")
    ]),
    CountryState(stateId: 2, stateName: "A", cities: [
      City(cityId: 3, cityName: "A1"),
      City(cityId: 4, cityName: "A2")
    ])
  ];

  int selectedStateId;
  int selectedCityId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedStateId = states[0].stateId;
    selectedCityId = states[0].cities[0].cityId;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'State'),
              value: selectedStateId,
              items: states.map((CountryState state) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: state.stateId,
                  child: Text(states
                      .singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == state.stateId)
                      .stateName),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (int StateId) {
                setState(() {
                  this.selectedCityId = states
                      .singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == StateId)
                      .cities[0]
                      .cityId; // set to first city for this state
                  this.selectedStateId = StateId;
                });
              },
            ),
            DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
              value: selectedCityId,
              items: states
                  .singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == selectedStateId)
                  .cities
                  .map((City city) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: city.cityId,
                  child: Text(states
                      .singleWhere((x) => x.stateId == selectedStateId)
                      .cities
                      .singleWhere((x) => x.cityId == city.cityId)
                      .cityName),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (int CityId) {
                setState(() {
                  this.selectedCityId = CityId;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time for the answer. I tried this version of the code and the primary reason this works over mine is that the CityId values are duplicated within each state. For my use case, the CityId values would be different for each state.

Comment: I have reproduce your issue. and update full code. in this case, you can use key: UniqueKey()

Comment: It works, but why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this example on the Flutter issues board and they could not duplicate on the latest stable version (1.20.2 as of this comment). I upgraded my flutter version (I was on 1.17.1) and the same code ran without issue, so for anyone experiencing the same issue I suggest updating your flutter version.

Comment: please see my updated answer, You can use key: UniqueKey() int City DropdownButtonFormField